# Pythonic way of setting path from list

Tags: python, list, filepath, os.path

I've been trying to make a program for my brother. One of the components of this would be to play an audio file. I have a list of about 90 audio files (please don't ask me why I have 90), and I am trying to randomly selected one and play it. However, to play it, I have to locate its path, and then plug the path into another section of my code (which I am still in the process of fixing). This is what I have so far:

```
import os, random

audio_playlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... all the way to 90]
sel_song = random.choice(audio_playlist)
song_path = None
base_directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                                              "songs")
```

Right now, this is how I create the path of the randomly selected song:

```
while song_path == None:
    if sel_song == 1:
        song_path = os.path.join(directory, "1.mp3")
    elif sel_song == 2:
        song_path = os.path.join(directory, "2.mp3")
# and i do this 90 times... :(
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this? Also, how do I make this so that setting my song's path so that I don't have to be writing hundreds of lines of code, but rather using something that's very simple and is only about 10-15 lines of code. Also note that the file in `song_path` is basically just the number with `.mp3` with it for simplicity.

Comment: Why not `s.path.join(directory, "{}.mp3".format(sel_song))`?

Comment: also: `audio_playlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, ... all the way to 90]` can be written as `audio_playlist = range(1, 91)`

Comment: Wow! That was really quick! That saves me!

Comment: @Zizouz212 Hardcoding "90", and the naming scheme, is never a good idea. Much better would be to just find out what audio files are there (with something like [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) ), and then use `choice` to get a random one. 

Doing it this way won't break anything you have now (it will keep working with the files you have now). But your code will be more **robust**, and adding files later will be much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly have it as to create the path

```
if 1<= sel_song <=90:
    s.path.join(directory, "{}.mp3".format(sel_song))
```

And as [emuiro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174299/pythonic-way-of-setting-path-from-list/28174371#comment44717782_28174299) suggested

```
audio_playlist = range(1, 91)
```

Is also a very Pythonic way

And as [Padraic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham) suggested,

```
audio_playlist = random.randint(1,91)
```

Is an even quicker way

Comment: This works wonders for me! Thank you so much! Accepting in 10 minutes... :D

Comment: `random.randint(1,90)` and forget choice

Comment: Although hardcoding "90" is never a very good idea. Much better would be to just find out what audio files are there (with something like [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) ), and then use `choice` to get a random one.

Comment: @RafaelLerm The OP himself has said that he needs that to be hard-coded :)

Comment: @BhargavRao I don't know if I have misunderstood him, but he says only "please don't ask me why I have 90". It seems that he says that it would be OK to hardcode 90, and the naming scheme ("`{n}.mp3`"), but I believe that if it can be done better and **more robust** than that, it is always a plus.

Comment: @RafaelLerm Yeah, Bro Agree with you. Do tag the OP in your comment :) He will require it in the next version most probably. Thanks again

Comment: Oh... Found this way after all the comments... Can't really do `random.randint` because the list can change... Mind you, @RafaelLerm thanks for the suggestion. I haven't actually heard of glob so I'll look into that. Great to learn something new!